# Executing function before page gets to window.print()

Tags: javascript

I have a page that calls window.print(); at the bottom of the page.  I have no way of accessing the code around window.print();  Its generated by the server and I can't touch it.  Basically because of IE I need to execute a bit of javascript before the print dialog comes up but after the page has loaded.  I can't do this because as soon as it gets to window.print(); the print dialog comes up.  I still need to print but first I need to run myFunction() then I can window.print();

```
<html><head></head><body></body><!--no access from here--><script>window.print();</script></html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to override it like so...

```
var _print = window.print;
window.print = function() {
  alert("Hi!");
  // do stuff
  _print();
}
```

Comment: I could've swore i tried that.  That works perfectly though!  Thanks!

Comment: Awww, beat me to the punch! +1.

Comment: @joe No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow!  To "accept" this as the answer, you can click the checkmark under the vote down-arrow.

Comment: @Josh: not for another 5 minutes he can't :-)

Comment: In Chrome 8 and other browsers, please note that using File · Print or otherwise executing print from browser chrome  (not page scripts) does NOT call `window.print` and this code will not be executed. Test case: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105727/web/print_function.html

Comment: @AlanH. Just tested with `Ctrl+P` in Chrome and I approve it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi anyone. How can this code also show "Hi!" when printing directly from browser File. print. can someone point me to right direction please.

Answer (score 10):

> *"Basically because of IE I need to..."*

If you only need support for IE, see the [*onbeforeprint*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536906(v=VS.85).aspx) event.

```
window.onbeforeprint = function () {
    // some code    
}
```

The benefit here is that the code will not run in browsers that don't support *onbeforeprint*, which is pretty much every browser except IE.

Answer (score 2):

This function works for all browsers including IE, no matter how the print is called:

```
/**
* Adds listeners for crossbrowser print callback
* @param callback - callback function
*/
function onPrint(callback) {
    window.matchMedia('print').addListener(query => query.matches ? callback() : null)
    window.addEventListener('beforeprint', () => callback())
}

onPrint(() => console.log('printing!'))
```

Be aware it may run the callback function twice, depending on the browser. This could be circumvented with a temporary flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting another `<script>` tag before the one you don't have access to eg:

```
<html><head></head><body></body><script>alert('Hello There !');</script><script>window.print();</script></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner, more modern way of handling this:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', () => {
    // before print, do something
});
```