# Printing Textarea Text - Full Length (Height)?

Tags: css, printing, textarea, print-style

I have a webform my client wants users to be able to print out. It works fine with a little styling using CSS, however, I have several `textaear` fields. If a user types more than the height of the textarea the type is cutoff when printed.

I have tried `textarea{height:100%;}` and `textarea{height:auto;}` in the print stylesheet but neither of those works.

Is there a way to resize the textarea field to the size of the text for the print only version? I would prefer a CSS solution if possible that I can insert into my print stylesheet. If this isn't possible javascript solution would work.

***Screenshot Comparison:***

[image: Screen vs Print]

Note: If I cannot affect just the print version I can considered [using JS to auto-resize the textarea field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454202/825757) as someone is typing.

Comment: Not a fully CSS only solution, but you could use a hidden `<div>` to hold a duplicate version of input (sync by JS), and use CSS to hide the `<textarea>` and show the `<div>` when print. This does sound like some meaningless overhead, but if the form is printed often I think it's OK.

Comment: @Passerby - I came across that idea after posting this question. It is one to consider, though as you say, may be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Same type of question has been already asked by someone.. you might take a look at this solution. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435906/print-when-textarea-has-overflow`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (adapted from [this JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303915/executing-function-before-page-gets-to-window-print/3303951#answer-3303951) and [this jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050605/display-all-textarea-rows-without-scrolling#answer-30050774)):

```
function resizeAndPrint() {   
    var _print = window.print;
    window.print = function() {
        $('textarea').each(function() {
            $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
        });
        _print();
    }
    window.print();
}
```

Comment: This answer may not always work as expected. The printout may use different widths and font sizes, while `resizeAndPrint()` will only take the screen display into account. See the note by `Passerby` and question number `4435906` for a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

This problem exist in **firefox** browser.

Please open the html file in **chrome** browser for printing text between `textarea` tags. There is no need apply style and script for printing **large text** of `textarea`.

**Steps to follow:**

1. open HTML file in chrome browser.
2. Click Ctrl + P.
3. Click on Save button ( Select PDF format ).
4. Open PDF file ( See all text between `textarea` **whether it is moves to second page if excess text contains**)
5. Click Print button.

Comment: Chrome trimmed the textareas just like Firefox when printing to PDF at work. Worse yet, Chrome printed everything as image, creating a huge 40 MB PDF out of less than 40 pages of form, so, about 1 MB per page (and that cannot be searched, indexed etc.) Firefox also does that some times, mainly when the Page uses custom fonts (disabling custom font usage usually solves the problem, though not always). I couldn't find a way to force Chrome to print text as text and not everything as image whenever it finds a slightly more complexly decorated Page.