# display all textarea rows without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display all textarea rows instead of having that vertical scroll. I have tried with css using min-height and max-height and height: auto but is not working.

```
.form-control{
    width:400px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 900px;
    height: auto;}
```

I don't really know if is possible to do that with css.

Maybe is possible with native javascript so I am trying something like this

```
function expandtext(expand) {
    while (expand.rows > 1 && expand.scrollHeight < expand.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("display all rows!")>
    }
}
```

I find something nice **[here](http://perplexed.co.uk/596_expanding_textarea_as_you_type.htm)** but it only increase and decrease rows , so how can I display all textarea rows without using scroll. DON'T NEED SOLUTION WITH FIXED HEIGHT, NEED SOMETHING DYNAMIC or other solutions that works only on chrome browser or only on firefox like Object.observe().

### Demo

```js
function expandtext(expand) {
  while (expand.rows > 1 && expand.scrollHeight < expand.offsetHeight) {
    console.log("display all rows!") >
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.form-control {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 900px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class=" form-group">
  <label>remove texarea scroll and display all rows</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" onkeydown="expandtext(this);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit, nisl eget dapibus condimentum, ipsum felis condimentum nisi, eget luctus est tortor vitae nunc. Nam ornare dictum augue, non bibendum sapien pulvinar ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras congue congue purus, quis imperdiet tellus ornare in. Nulla facilisi. Nulla elementum posuere odio ut ultricies. Nullam tempus tincidunt elit eget posuere. Pellentesque sit amet
    tellus sapien. Praesent sed iaculis turpis. Nam quis nibh diam, sed mattis orci. Nullam ornare adipiscing congue. In est orci, consectetur in feugiat non, consequat vitae dui. Mauris varius dui a dolor convallis iaculis.</textarea>
</div>
<div class=" form-group">
  <label>remove texarea scroll and display all rows</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" onkeydown="expandtext(this);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque suscipit, nisl eget dapibus condimentum, ipsum felis condimentum nisi, eget luctus est tortor vitae nunc. Nam ornare dictum augue, non bibendum sapien pulvinar ut.</textarea>
</div>
```

External [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/292/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple jQuery solution is:

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
});
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/291/)

As you need a plain JavaScript solution, use following script that was created by [User panzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277767/panzi). You can view the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/1762224).

```
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/296/)

Comment: You need to call this every-time you type.

Comment: @ketan  I would like a solution with native javascript because I am not using jQuery library :|

Comment: @mcmwhfy: But your demo is using jQuery...

Comment: @ Mr. Polywhirl my example run without jQuery

Comment: Did you credit the [author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/1762224)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl sorry i didn't getting you.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Ohh thank you i really didn't know about it. I get this JavaScript solution from my friend.

Answer (score 12):

No Javascript required.

You can display a no-scroll (ie. automatically re-sizing) editable text area with the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.textarea {
  width:250px;
  min-height:50px;
  height:auto;
  border:2px solid rgba(63,63,63,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">
```

Comment: I know this html5 attribute, is quite awesome but unfortunatley is not working on all browsers :(

Answer (score 6):

The Mozilla Developer Network has an [*Autogrowing textarea example*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#Autogrowing_textarea_example) on their `HTMLTextAreaElement` page. You should definitely check this out if you want to stay away from CSS3 solutions that can break on older browsers.

Here is the code from the example.

> The following example shows how to make a textarea really autogrow while typing.

```js
function autoGrow(oField) {
  if (oField.scrollHeight > oField.clientHeight) {
    oField.style.height = oField.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
textarea.noscrollbars {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your comments</legend>
    <p>
      <textarea class="noscrollbars" onkeyup="autoGrow(this);"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### Autoadjust

This example will take care of the case where you remove lines.

```js
function autoAdjustTextArea(o) {
  o.style.height = '1px'; // Prevent height from growing when deleting lines.
  o.style.height = o.scrollHeight + 'px';
}


// =============================== IGNORE =====================================
// You can ignore this, this is for generating the random characters above.
var chars = '\n abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
var randRange=function(min,max){return max==null?randRange(0,min):~~(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);}
var randChars=function(chrs,len){return len>0?chrs[randRange(chrs.length)]+randChars(chrs,len-1):'';}
// ============================== /IGNORE =====================================


// Get a reference to the text area.
var txtAra = document.getElementsByClassName('noscrollbars')[0];
// Generate some random characters of length between 150 and 300.
txtAra.value = randChars(chars,randRange(150,300));
// Trigger the event.
autoAdjustTextArea(txtAra);
```

```css
textarea.noscrollbars {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px; /** This is via your example. */
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your comments</legend>
    <p>
      <textarea class="noscrollbars" onkeyup="autoAdjustTextArea(this);"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: this is great but is not answer to my question, display all textarea rows, he is running only onkeyup :(

Comment: @mcmwhfy: Who is "he"?

Comment: :| the function is running only onkeyup and when I am loading the page is not doing nothing, maybe if I call this function on other event like onchange

Comment: Well, this is for live growing and shrinking... So you want it to happen when the page is loaded?

Comment: onload I want to see all rows and onchange I want to have that increase and decrease solution that already works in your example. (o.style.height = o.scrollHeight)  also need onchange to increase height when I am copying something inside that javascript using ctrl + v.  The solution of User panzi is great but that Object.observe() is buggy an others browsers :(

Comment: @mcmwhfy: Well, I added some random text to the text area and triggered the event.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery and some logic I have tried to do what you need.
Here is the jsfiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/45zsdzds/

HTML:

```
<textarea class="myClass" id="FurnishingDetails" name="FurnishingDetails" id="FurnishingDetails"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#FurnishingDetails').text('hello\nhello1\nhello2\nhello3\nhello4\nhello5');
String.prototype.lines = function() { return $('#FurnishingDetails').text().split(/\r*\n/); }
String.prototype.lineCount = function() { return $('#FurnishingDetails').text().lines().length; }
$('#FurnishingDetails').css('height', ($('#FurnishingDetails').text().lineCount() + 1) + 'em');
```

CSS:

```
textarea[name='FurnishingDetails']{
 height:2em;  
}
```

Used [How to get the number of lines in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea) to add a String prototype inorder to get the linecount.