# Protractor: How to test window.print()

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to test print functionality of a button, like:

```
it('print document', function(){
    element(by.id('print-button')).click();
    expect(window.print());
});
```

I want to test browser print dialog box. How to do this?

Comment: You can with the help of Sikuli JAVA API in selenium. Please check this my post and also my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213535/how-to-test-print-preview-of-chrome-browser-using-chrome-webdriver

Comment: @nitinchawda yup, but this is not java or python, so Sikuli is probably not the best option. Plus, the solution would be not quite reliable since it would depend on a specific browser, hence a specific image of a print dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browser's print dialog is out of scope of selenium, **it is not under selenium's control**. There is no way to solve your problem reliably with `protractor`/`selenium` only.

Besides, you don't need to test the browser and it's ability to open print dialogs. What you can do (not tested), is to test whether `window.print` is called on `print-button` click by redefining `window.print()` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303951/771848)):

```
browser.setScriptTimeout(10);

var printButton = element(by.id('print-button'));

var result = browser.executeAsyncScript(function (elm, callback) {
    function listener() {
        callback(true);
    }

    window.print = listener;
    elm.click();
}, printButton.getWebElement());

expect(result).toBe(true);
```

See also:

- [Handling Print Dialog Using Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/937)
- [Selenium WebDriver : Verify Print Window dialog displayed on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014233/selenium-webdriver-verify-print-window-dialog-displayed-on-the-page)
- [How to handle print dialog in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537103/how-to-handle-print-dialog-in-selenium)